# how do i add animation on update element.subscribersCount?

Tags: reactjs

I get the data and update it every second.
how do i add animation on update element.subscribersCount

displaying:

```
getChannel() {
 this.api
  .getChannels()
    .then(channels => {
      this.setState({
        channels: channels
      })
    })
}

componentDidMount() {
 this.getChannel();
 setInterval(() => {
  this.api.updateChannel()
    .then(channels => {
      this.setState({
        channels: channels
      })
    })
 }, 1000);
}
```

that's how I display the data

```
 renderChannels(element) {
  return (
    <div className="box">
            <h1>
              {element.subscribersCount}
            </h1>
    </div>
  )
 }
```

Comment: What kind of animation do you want to add ?

Comment: Every second the data is updated, you need to add any smooth animation of the update of the number
http://test2.admintes.site

Comment: Hello! What kind of animation are you thinkin' of? Some fade-out/fade-in effect? Or some counting-up/counting-down? In the second case, you can use already existing Component (https://github.com/javierbyte/react-number-easing)

Comment: Matteo GesmundoThank you. that's unsettling